# how to stub a function that returns an object in QUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, qunit, sapui5, stubbing

I have the following lines in my SAPUI5 app

```
var dateVal = controls.awardDate.getDateValue();
var month = dateVal.getMonth();
```

awardDate is a datepicker the user enters a date on and returns a javascript date object. This is a snippet of my qunit to test this element.

```
awardDate: {
  getValue: getInvalidValue,
  getValueState: getValueStateWarning,
  setValue: setValue,
  getDatevalue: getDateValue
 }
```

In my qunit I get an error saying that the object doesn't support property or method 'getDateValue'. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to stub this function when it returns an object. Other tests I have do it this way

```
var getValue = sinon.stub().returns('');
```

where I get an empty string.
so my attempt at to do it with the datepicker is

```
var getDateValue = sinon.stub().returns(new Date());
```

but this doesn't work. I still get the same error. Has anyone done this before?

**edit/update:** I was able to fix part of the problem by doing the following

```
var getValueDate = sinon.stub().returns(Object, function(){ });
```

Now the problem I have is the same error but for getMonth() which returns a string. All other variables are global but dateVal is created on the spot when the user updates the datepicker. Any ideas on how to proceed on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to solve this. I had to make the Object type a specific Date object like this

```
 var getValueDate = sinon.stub().returns(new Date()), function(){ });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
var getValueDate = sinon.stub(controls.awardDate, 'getDateValue');
var month  = {
    getMonth: sinon.stub()
}
getValueDate.returns([month]);
```